# C#, ASP.NET core | SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-layers

I was experimenting in ASP.NET Core with getting data from my small database.
I want to select 2 random rows from my table, but I can not get it to work.

My database table:

[image: My databasetable]

I figured the error I because my `SqlCommand` is not correct, but I don't know how to make it correct.

My DAL:

```
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Karakter ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;", connection);

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
                        {
                            KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                            KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                            KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
                        };
            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }

        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```

The queries that I have tried:

- `SELECT * FROM Karatker ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;`
- `SELECT * FROM Karakter ORDER BY RAND() TOP 2;`
- `SELECT * FROM Karakter TOP 2;`
- `SELECT * FROM Karakter Limit 2;`
- `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter ODER BY RAND();`
- `SELECT TOP 2 FROM Karakter ODER BY RAND();`

All the above queries throw the same error except for the keyword.

Can anyone help?

**Edit**: when I tried this query:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM dbo.Karakter;
```

it displays the first 2 records of the database, this prooves that the error is not a problem from the other layers, the only problem is the query itself.

Comment: Why don't you just consult the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `SELECT`?? It would have clearly showed that **(1)** `LIMIT` is **NOT** a valid T-SQL keyword, and **(2)** the correct syntax is `SELECT TOP (n) ......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM Karakter 
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Found it on this site: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Comment: NEWID() is not found in your table column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter ORDER BY ID ;`

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.